# No instance of function template with <typename T, int size> matches the argument list: rapidjson::GenericArray

Tags: c++, arrays, json, templates, rapidjson

I have a template function in C++, meant for converting a `rapidjson::GenericArray` into an `std::array`:

```cpp
namespace jsonutils
{
    template <typename T, int size> 
    inline std::array<T, size> toArray(
        const rapidjson::GenericArray<false, rapidjson::Value>* value
    )
    {
        std::array<T, size> result;
        for (rapidjson::SizeType i = 0; i < value.Size(); i++)
        {
            result[i] = value[i];
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

However, when I try the following:

```cpp
const rapidjson::GenericArray<false, rapidjson::Value>* bNode = 
    &node["b"].GetArray();
int size = bNode->Size();
std::array<int, 3> b = jsonutils::toArray<int, size>(bNode);
```

I get the following errors:

- E0304: no instance of function template "`jsonutils::toArray`" matches the argument list

  - Argument types are: (`const rapidjson::GenericArray<false, rapidjson::Value>`)
- C2672: '`jsonutils::toArray`': no matching overloaded function found

When I hover over `jsonutils::toArray` in Visual Studio, it lists the template as `template<class T, int size>`.

Why does this call not work?

Comment: The template parameter must be a compile-time constant. You are trying to pass a variable, `size`, whose value is only known at run time. `int size = bNode->Size(); jsonutils::toArray<int, size>(bNode);` isn't gonna fly.

Comment: Function parameters are not `constexpr`.